# Rails jsonb column as nested `attribute` types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using a `jsonb` column on a model that has the following schema:

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  points: [{
   x: 0,
   y: 2,
  }, {
   x: 2,
   y: 3,
  }],
}
```

I want to use nested [ActiveModel::attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods/attribute) methods to (de)serialize the data in order to be able to use ActiveModel validations on the json.

This is what I tried:

```
# app/models/parent_model.rb
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :child, ChildModel.new
end
```

```
# app/models/child_model.rb
class ChildModel < ActiveModel::Type::Value
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name

  attribute :points, Point.new, array: true

  def cast(value)
    case value
    when String
      decoded = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(value) rescue nil
      ChildModel.new(decoded) unless decoded.nil?
    when Hash
      ChildModel.new(value)
    when ChildModel
      value
    end
  end

  def serialize(value)
    value&.attributes&.to_json
  end

  def changed_in_place?(raw_old_value, new_value)
    deserialize(raw_old_value) != new_value
  end
end
```

```
# app/models/point.rb
class Point < ActiveModel::Type::Value
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def cast(value)
    case value
    when String
      decoded = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(value) rescue nil
      Point.new(decoded) unless decoded.nil?
    when Hash
      Point.new(value)
    when Point
      value
    end
  end

  def serialize(value)
    value&.attributes&.to_json
  end

  def changed_in_place?(raw_old_value, new_value)
    deserialize(raw_old_value) != new_value
  end
end
```

Here are the problems with this:

- `Point` and `ChildModel` have attributes `limit`, `precision` and `scale`. They seem to be coming from `ActiveModel::Type::Value`, but I'm wondering why? Is there a different base class I should use?
- The `child` attribute seems to get saved to the database as `nil`, even though it is set upon instantiation of a `ParentModel`

What is the right way to do what I'm trying to do in rails?

Comment: Could try `Store`: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that's not exactly what I'm trying to do. As far as I can see, this won't give me `ActiveModel` validations for the nested models. From what I see the stored attributes will also not be nested but only prefixed with `<prefix>_`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question... but I see many questions around here relating to the shortcomings of using jsonb or array column types that could be avoided if a different table structure had been used. My suggestion is:

```rb
ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :child_model
end

ChildModel < ApplicationRecord
  # fields could be name, x1, x2, y1, y2
  belongs_to :parent_model
end
```

Your life will be easier!

Comment: I know that your suggestion would be the "relational approach", but I have good reasons to use a `jsonb` column, so your suggestion doesn't help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [attr_json gem](https://github.com/jrochkind/attr_json) now, which does exactly what I need. I thought it would be possible with "vanilla rails", though. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`serialize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) instead of `attributes`.

Something like:

```
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord 
  serialize :child, ChildModel
  
  validate :child_valid?

private 
  def child_valid? 
    errors.add(:child, 'is invalid') unless child.valid? 
  end 
end 

class ChildModel
  include ActiveModel::API
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :name
  attr_writer :points

  # add validations
  validate :points_valid?
  
  def initialize(h)
    self.points = h.delete('points')&.map{ |point| Point.new(point)}
    super
  end

  def points 
    @points ||= []
  end 
  
  def self.dump(value)
    value.to_json(include: :points)
  end

  def self.load(string)
    obj = self.new(JSON.parse(string)) 
  end

  def attributes 
    {'name'=> nil}
  end 

private 
  def points_valid?
    points.all?(&:valid?)
  end 

end  

class Point
  include ActiveModel::API
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  
  attr_accessor :x,:y

  # add validations

  def attributes 
    {'x'=> nil, 'y' => nil}
  end 
end
```